# Cassandra 1.1.1 crashes while inserting heavy data using Hector 1.0.5

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am using Cassandra 1.1.1 and Using Hector 1.0.5, am trying to insert data (heavy volume) in to a column family. During execution of my program, the cassandra server crashes and displays the Out-of-memory error. After that I am left with no option than quitting the server. This gets repeated for one column family where I am trying to store html file(s) content and I never get a chance to complete it. The html file contents varies from 225 KB data to 700 KB data for one row and I am trying to insert almost 1000 records.

---

In the program it throws the below

```
Exception in thread "main" me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.getClientFromLBPolicy(HConnectionManager.java:393)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:249)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:97)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
    at com.epocrates.soa.rx.util.DiseaseImporter.insertDisease(DiseaseImporter.java:207)
    at com.epocrates.soa.rx.util.DiseaseImporter.batchProcess(DiseaseImporter.java:81)
    at com.epocrates.soa.rx.
```

util.DiseaseImporter.main(DiseaseImporter.java:37)

### In System.log, I find the below

```
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Map failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:127)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.freshSegment(CommitLogSegment.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator.createFreshSegment(CommitLogAllocator.java:244)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator.access$500(CommitLogAllocator.java:49)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogAllocator.java:104)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:758)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:119)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:755)
    ... 7 more

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: ThreadPoolExecutor has shut down
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor$1.rejectedExecution(DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:767)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:658)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.insertLocal(StorageProxy.java:457)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.sendToHintedEndpoints(StorageProxy.java:314)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$2.apply(StorageProxy.java:119)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.performWrite(StorageProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.mutate(StorageProxy.java:193)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.doInsert(CassandraServer.java:637)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.internal_batch_mutate(CassandraServer.java:587)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.batch_mutate(CassandraServer.java:595)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$batch_mutate.getResult(Cassandra.java:3112)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$batch_mutate.getResult(Cassandra.java:3100)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that you've run out of address space to map commitlog segments into.

Best solution: upgrade to a 64bit JVM.

Worse solution: in cassandra.yaml, set commitlog_segment_size_in_mb and commitlog_total_space_in_mb both to 16.

This isn't the first time this has come up; I've opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4422 to improve the defaults.

Comment: Thanks for your reply John. I went with the worse solution as it would take some time for me testing the best solution.It worked out when I say "commitlog_total_space_in_mb" to 16.